# How to remove a nested JS object inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I'm trying to remove a specific object when a property matches my parameter (Here when the name of the wheel is "Michelin") but I can't make it work...

How could I do it ?

```js
var car = {
  type: "Fiat",
  model: "500",
  color: "White",
  wheels: [{
    name: "Goodyear",
    color: "Red"
  }, {
    name: "Goodyear",
    color: "Yellow"
  }, {
    name: "Goodyear",
    color: "Black"
  }, {
    name: "Michelin",
    color: "Blue"
  }]
};

$.each(car.wheels, function() {
  if (this.name == "Michelin") {
    delete this;
  }
})
console.log(car);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't use "this" inside a function. Use the iterated object.

Comment: The callback function takes 2 arguments. The first is the index, the second is the iterated object, use that.

Comment: Alexandru's answer is spot on. In addition, I would suggest _never_ using `$.each()`. It is a messed up function that evolved piecemeal. Use `.forEach()` or a more appropriate function like `.filter()` as in Alexandru's code. If you _must_ use `$.each()` for some reason (no, really, don't!) at least don't use `this` at all inside the callback. That makes things really confusing. Instead, use the two named arguments to the callback as doublesharp mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **callback** function for `$.each` method takes two parameters:

```
$.each(car.wheels, function(i,item) {
   if (item.name == "Michelin") {
       delete car.wheels[i];
   }
});
```

But this is **not** the **best** solution.Usually, `delete` operator is used to **delete** properties from an object.If you use it on array, **delete** will remove the array item, but will not **reindex** the array or update its **length**. This makes it appears as if it is undefined:

```js
var car = {
      type: "Fiat",
      model: "500",
      color: "White",
      wheels: [{
        name: "Goodyear",
        color: "Red"
      }, {
        name: "Goodyear",
        color: "Yellow"
      }, {
        name: "Goodyear",
        color: "Black"
      }, {
        name: "Michelin",
        color: "Blue"
      }]
};
$.each(car.wheels, function(i,item) {
    if (item.name == "Michelin") {
       delete car.wheels[i];
    }
});
console.log(car);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The solution is to use `filter` method which accepts a **callback** provided function applied on every item in the array.

```js
var car = {
      type: "Fiat",
      model: "500",
      color: "White",
      wheels: [{
        name: "Goodyear",
        color: "Red"
      }, {
        name: "Goodyear",
        color: "Yellow"
      }, {
        name: "Goodyear",
        color: "Black"
      }, {
        name: "Michelin",
        color: "Blue"
      }]
 };
car.wheels=car.wheels.filter(function(wheel){
  return wheel.name!='Michelin';
});
console.log(car);
```

Comment: @doublesharp, have a look now.

Comment: Your answer was better before the edit that added the `$.each()` code. :-) `.filter()` is a great solution. `$.each()` is a messed up function and is best avoided for code like this.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Also, @MichaelGeary , thank you for your comment, I'll try to use the functions you mentioned from now on!

Comment: @MichaelGeary, I know..delete operator is used usually to delete properties of an object. I want to show the OP how to use each method.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery grep funtion :

```js
var car = {
  type: "Fiat",
  model: "500",
  color: "White",
  wheels: [{
    name: "Goodyear",
    color: "Red"
  }, {
    name: "Goodyear",
    color: "Yellow"
  }, {
    name: "Goodyear",
    color: "Black"
  }, {
    name: "Michelin",
    color: "Blue"
  }]
};
car.wheels= $.grep(car.wheels,function(wheel){
  return wheel.name!='Michelin';
});
console.log(car);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```